# Sending a PUSH notification from OS X/Mac

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to use the parse OS X SDK to end push notification?

As soon as I added :

```
#import <ParseOSX/PFInstallation.h>
#import <ParseOSX/PFPush.h>
```

I started getting build errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInstallation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SendMessageController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFPush", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SendMessageController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PFPush` and `PFInstallation` are not available on OS X. From the documentation (as of SDK 1.4.2):

> This class is currently for iOS only. There is no PFInstallation for Parse applications running on OS X, because they cannot receive push notifications.

If you want to send a push notification, you'll have to use Cloud Code or the REST-API from within your OS X application. See here for the syntax [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/REST) and use e.g. `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionTask` for making the request.

Comment: Ok. Gotcha. I wasn't trying to send a PUSH to OS X, but rather send a push to IOS from an IOS application.