# OS X Push Notifications with Parse

Tags: macos, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to find a way to integrate push notifications on OS X with Parse. It's been a long and tedious process, so please bear with me while I explain my situation.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068902/sending-a-push-notification-from-os-x-mac) explains that currently push notifications are not supported natively on OS X. However, it does mention that I can somehow implement Parse through their REST API. Someone [also posted](https://parse.com/questions/why-dont-you-support-push-notifications-for-osx) on Parse's forums, and the same answer was given.

I tried following the REST API docs [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/REST) and [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#push), while also following [Parse's iOS SDK push documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS). I've implemented my own version of the PFInstallation class, and also some other methods which handle in the PFObject class that allow data to be synchronised with Parse, with success. I can now synchronise with Parse the deviceToken I get when I call the registerForRemoteNotifications method.

However, I am now stuck at the stage where I am trying to send push notifications from the Parse dashboard (also tried sending a test push notification through the REST API) and notification doesn't get sent due to **Parse not having my Mac OS X APNs certificate**. I can only find a way to upload an **iOS APNs certificate**, which obviously won't work with my Mac application.

So, to sum up, **is there any way that Parse push notifications can be integrated into a Mac OS X application?** I've tried searching for other answers, which simply end with a statement that the Parse Push API isn't available on Mac (because it isn't supported?) and that you should try and use the REST API (which I've tried doing, but can't because there isn't a way for me to specify my Mac APNs certificate).

Thank you so much for reading this; I hope somebody has the answer! If someone also has an answer for why Parse doesn't support Mac OS X push notifications, I'd love to know why too! Alternatively, if there are any other great providers for Mac OS X push notifications, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fully supported now with the latest SDK.
Read more on our blog: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-push-for-os-x/